# Execute Code only after Multiple Promises Fulfilled in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an EmberJS ArrayController. I want to have a computed property on this controller, `neurons`, that is a subset of the `model` property.  The subset is computed based on a toggle button in the sidebar which is bound to `currentDataset`. Another computed property, `activePlots` then depends on `neurons`; the `Neuron` model has a `hasMany` relationship to `Plot`, and `activePlots` loads all the plot objects associated with each neuron object in `neurons`.

Currently I'm trying to do this with `mapBy`, but I'm running into a problem. Each retrieval of a `Neuron` object's `plots` returns a `PromiseArray`. I need to manipulate all the returned plots at once. I understand I can call `then` on the promise result of an individual call `get('plots')`, but how do I execute code only after the `get('plots')` call has returned for ALL neurons?

```
neurons: ( ->
    @get('model').filterBy('dataset', @get('currentDataset'))
).property('model', 'currentDataset'),

activePlots: ( ->
  plots = @get('neurons').mapBy('plots')
  # ...code to execute after all plots have loaded
).property('neurons')
```

UPDATE: Picture of console output from `console.log(plotSets)` inside the `then` callback to

```
Ember.RSVP.all(@get('neurons').mapBy('plots')).then (plotSets) -> 
  console.log(plotSets)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a handy method for combining promises: `Ember.RSVP.all(ary)` takes an array of promises and becomes a promise that is resolved when all the promises in the input array are resolved.  If one is rejected, the `all()` promise is rejected.

This is very handy, for example, when firing off multiple parallel network requests and continuing when all of them are done.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I've implemented your solution with `Em.RSVP.all(@get('neurons').mapBy('plots')).then(gotPlots)`, where `gotPlots` is my handler function. I am finding something I don't understand, though-- inside `gotPlots`, when I look at what is passed in (in a parameter called `plotSets`, which seems to me that it should be an `Array` of `Array`s of `Plot` objects?), I find that the content is not what I expect. It seems to be an array of `Class`es?  I am posting a picture of my console output above.  I can't figure out how to access the actual plot objects.

Comment: It should be the same thing you were getting back before.  BTW, if you want to see the "ember types" in the console you can use `console.log(Ember.inspect(plotSets))`.

Comment: OK, yeah I've got things working now. Thanks for your help and the tip on `Ember.inspect`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Steve said you can watch the nuerons.length and use Ember.scheduleOnce to schedule an update (guessed coffeescript below)

```
activePlots: [],

watchNuerons: ( ->
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, @updatePlots); 
).observes('nueron.length'),

updatePlots: ( ->
  plots = @get('neurons').mapBy('plots')
  # ...code to execute after all plots have loaded
  @set('activePlots', plots)
)
```